# New monitor recurring blackout: How to isolate my monitor supply from my refrigerator?

Tags: display, power-supply

**Context**

My new Philips monitor's power supply is very sensitive of transients of electricity network in our home, means if refrigerator starts or stops, the supply is (I suppose) trying to guard overvoltage, so turns of supply, then back, but my monitor takes 5 seconds to pick up the signal. Those 5 seconds blackouts, repeated dozens times daily drive me crazy after a month of usage (I thought I can live with this, but realized I can not)

The fridge and the monitor are on different circuit with different electric fuse, but my home has only one phase, so further isolation is not possible

**Question**

(I am not sure if UPS would be a solution, because in a entry level model when there is supply, it will work pass through (will it?) so the spike will pass through, so the **overvoltage guard in the PSU of the monitor** will react **off**/on, so the monitory will black out for secs...)

Is there any cheap solution I can try? Because of my fridge is the only source of transients (currently :-), maybe isolating the fridge itself could work.

Any ideas for a simple stupid solution which is silent and worth trying?

Comment: I'd send it back.

Comment: I don't get why you assume that a UPS will have an impact on the noise level. As they do start as low as 50$ or so there probably is something you could use. After all you are not really interested in its capacity. If you limit yourself like that just getting a different display is the most probable solution.

Comment: @Tetsujin: you mean the fridge :-)? My prev. Panasonic TV did the very same, and also there is a same issue with LG posted here, just the OP did not diagnosed that it is because the spike in voltage, and the too sensitive overvoltage guard in the supply

Comment: @Seth: I realized if the UPS is working in passthrough when there is a supply, then the spike will pass through, so the PSU of the monitory will react, off, then on, and the we are the very same situation.

Comment: Have you tried any of the various surge protectors that are available on the market? https://www.amazon.co.uk/Power-Strip-Surge-Protector/s?k=Power+Strip+Surge+Protector does the problem persist after using one? Otherwise what you want is an **online** UPS which always does its own power conversion regardless of the input voltage. They are more expensive as a general rule.

Comment: Whenever a UPS works in passthrough mode or not depends on the kind of design its using. A line-interactive UPS might already be sufficient. Depending on what's actually tripping that behavior there might also be a different solution to filter e.g. for noise.

Comment: @Mokubai, do surge protectors filtering out spikes (keeping the voltage) or just interrupting the output in case a spike occurs in the input? (in latter case the monitor will blackout... so we are when we started)

Comment: Surge protectors tend to exclusively clamp the peak voltage, they do not simply disconnect.

Comment: Many thx for all. I am going to do my homework now, first trying cheapo surge protectors either in monitor side either on fridge side, then try an economic line-interactive UPS. I will be back with the result.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the mains wiring, perhaps in the fuse box where an electrician would be the best person to check it for safety. The voltage should not drop that much just for a fridge switching on.